# WordPress theme error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in theme file

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I've just been racking my brain over this one so I hope someone would kindly help me out if possible.

My site is broken right now - it's only showing this error "Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/agency/library/init.php on line 31." 
I am not able to get to the WordPress admin login or anything. This occurred when I attempted to update the a WordPress theme.

While trying to research an answer, I came across tons of people having this similar error. Most people were able to fix it by removing & out of said line of code in said php file of the error (in my case it would be line 31 of init.php). This unfortunately did not work for me.

I also tried renaming the Agency theme folder to see if WordPress would load up a different default theme. It did not. I got the same error. I also tried deleting the theme folder via FTP. Even though it was deleted, I still got the same error.

I also tried disabling plugins by renaming the plugin folder. No luck there either.

What could it be that I am missing here? Do I need to delete the theme folder from cPanel perhaps? I am incredibly boggled by how I seem to get the same error from a theme folder that doesn't exist (after I deleted the folder).

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this error. Here is the code the error is referencing - I put the &s back in since it did not seem to matter whether they were there or not.

```
28    function agency_nav_menu_objects($items) {
29
30    foreach ($items as &$item) {
31        if ( agency_get_menu_object_items($item->ID, &$items) ) {
32            $item->classes[] = 'sub';
33            break;
34        }
35    }
36    return $items;
37 }
```

Comment: change `&$items` to `$items`

Comment: If you deleted the folder, and still got the same error...you deleted the wrong folder.

Comment: Diggy - I did try that out, but unfortunately it did not work for me. 
Mevius - I definitely deleted the right folder. It was the agency theme folder under public_html/wp-content/themes/. I even tried renaming the twentyeleven theme to agency to see if it would still happen, and alas, I got the same error.

Thank you both for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed all &$items to $items in init.php?

Comment: Yes I did, but it did not fix the error. I thought that would fix it for sure too.

Comment: Can you send a copy of your theme folder to me , i want test it in my localhost. if you want send it to info@gigatek.se